# In Blender, How do you split/extract multiple shapes from inside one object into multiple objects?

Tags: blender

Ok while watching a tutorial I stupidly missed the part that you have to add a shape in object mode to create a new object. Well I now have 5 shapes in one object and can't color them differently. If I wasn't as far in I would just recreate them, but I would be so grateful if someone knew of a way to extract them into new objects or break apart the single object i have.

Object created from UV Sphere and added 3 other UV Spheres and a Cylinder inside that object.

Im using Blender 2.5, if that matters.

**While waiting for an answer I found another way to make them different objects. I went into Object mode duplicated my object 4 other times and deleted all but one shape from each duplication... allowing me to have a shape per object.**

*NOTE : I will still give anyone credit for an answer if they can actually tell me if there is a way to break one object into multiple.*

Comment: Accept the guy who answered correctly...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go into vertex mode with <kbd>Tab</kbd>, select the vertices or faces you want to remove, then remove with <kbd>P</kbd>.  See [the docs](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:Manual/Modeling/Objects/Groups_and_Parenting#Separating_Objects) for more information.